# Does not work "require" in React

Tags: requirejs, reactjs

I can not understand the library https://github.com/jquense/react-widgets
There is a path, for example: lib/NumberInput.js

This file has the code:

```
'use strict';

var babelHelpers = require('./util/babelHelpers.js');

var React = require('react'),
    CustomPropTypes = require('./util/propTypes'),
    localizers = require('./util/configuration').locale;

var format = function format(props) {
  return props.format || localizers.number.formats['default'];
};

//.... code code code .....
```

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
    <script src="react-widgets/lib/NumberInput.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

In the console write error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

I connected the library. http://requirejs.org/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
    <script src="require.js"></script>
    <script src="react-widgets/lib/NumberInput.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Again, I have an error:

> Uncaught Error: Module name "util/babelHelpers.js" has not been loaded
>   yet for context: _. Use require([])

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

React widgets are distributing by NPM; you can use them due node.js built-in `require` module loader. To make node modules available for the browser, you need  to create a single bundle (contains React itself, widgets, maybe other modules, and your code) using [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), and include it to the web page.

Comment: BTW, `Require.js` references to AMD module style, as well as node-like `require` modules reference to CommonJS style.

Comment: I created index.js file and HTML page:

var NumberPicker = require('./react-widgets/lib/NumberPicker.js');
//var React = require('react');

console.log(NumberPicker);
//console.log(React);

window.loaded = function () {
 React.render(React.createElement(NumberPicker, null), document.body);
}

Comment: I created index.js file and HTML page:

var NumberPicker = require('./react-widgets/lib/NumberPicker.js');
window.loaded = function () {
 React.render(React.createElement(NumberPicker, null), document.body);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
 <script src="packed.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="loaded();"></body>
</html>
http://i10.pixs.ru/storage/3/6/0/2015091117_5809543_18760360.png

How to connect styles? And I have an error. How to fix it?